# jQuery image swap not working

Tags: jquery

Hey so I found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dEHZZ/1/

```
$('div#thumbs img').click( function() {
$('#mainimg img').prop('src', $(this).prop('src'));
return false;  //stop link from navigating
})
```

scrolling through some questions here,
however its not working when i try to implement it here http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/products/IR155R926.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code is run BEFORE your DOModel is read and ready to be manipulated

**Use a document `ready` function**

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready to be manipulated

    $('div#thumbs img').click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();  //stop link from navigating
        $('#mainimg img').prop('src', this.src );
    });

});
```

Additionally, in your code I cannot see no link, so actually you dint need any `return false` not `event-preventDefault()` (I used)

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Worked beautifully, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in ready method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div#thumbs img').click( function() {
   $('#mainimg img').prop('src', $(this).prop('src'));
   return false;  //stop link from navigating
   })
});
```

You instantiate your code before the dom elements are ready.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I can see why someone would. You need to explain that your second example (and by the way, .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on()) would need to be run after the div has been created in the DOM. Anywhere before that would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your jQuery in a [document ready call](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#thumbs img').click( function() {
        $('#mainimg img').prop('src', $(this).prop('src'));
        return false;  //stop link from navigating
    })
});
```

jsFiddle does this for you automatically which is why it's working there.